# "_" not defined microsoft visual studio

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

Im working on a page that should display like this http://jsfiddle.net/grahamwalsh/6RnXM/
When i debug it in microsoft visual studious i get  Uncaught ReferenceError: _ is not defined

I looked at other questions similar to this and added  to my html file and now i get Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeType' of null which seems to be referencing my knockout script

here is my full code

Voting (html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Voting</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/0.10.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/knockout-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="Voting.js"></script>
<link rel="styleSheet" type="text/css" href="voting.css">
</head>
<body>
<div data-bind="foreach: items">
    <div class="profile" data-bind="text: name, click: $parent.clicked, enable: active, css:{highlight: active()}"></div>
</div>

<hr>
<h2>Selected Card</h2>
<div data-bind="foreach: selectedItems">
    <div data-bind="text: name"></div>
</div>
<input type="button" data-bind="click: save" value="Save">

</body>

</html>
```

Voting (Css)

```
.profile 
{
width: 50px;
height: 80px;
color: black;
background-color: silver;
border: 1px solid black;
float: left;
line-height: 80px;
text-align: center;
margin: 2px;
 }
 .highlight 
{
background: yellow !important;
border:1px solid #000;
color: black;
}
```

Voting (js)

```
function Card(number) {
this.active = ko.observable(false);
this.name = ko.observable(number);
}

var model = function () {
var cards = [1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 20, 40, 100];
for (var i = 0 ; i < cards.length ; i++)
    cards[i] = new Card(cards[i]);
var items = ko.observableArray(cards)
var selectedItems = ko.computed(function () {
    return _.filter(items(), function (item) {
        return item.active();
    });
})

var clicked = function (item) {
    items().forEach(function (item) { item.active(false) });
    item.active(!this.active());
};

var save = function () {
    alert("sending items \n" + ko.toJSON(selectedItems()));
}

return {
    items: items,
    selectedItems: selectedItems,
    save: save,
    clicked: clicked
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because you have not added 'underscore' javascript library in your code here.

In jsfiddle, you can refer it via provided tools  but in your code you need to add it in the head section.

So, add this line to your head section

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.4.4/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

OR if you have added underscore library to your script folder, then add this line

```
  <script src="Scripts/underscore.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The OP's code shows a script tag for lodash, which is a drop-in replacement for underscore.